# Symfony phpunit undefined method Kernel::bootstrapEnv()

Tags: symfony, phpunit

After installing PHPUnit following :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html

`# In bin/phpunit
App\Kernel`

To its path in my project. I get the error :

```
Call to undefined method My\Bundle\Path\Kernel::bootstrapEnv()
```

When I run bin/phpunit

Can anyone help me understand the reasons it's behaving this way? I'm starting to believe, the bin/phpunit script has not been updated for Symfony 4.

Thank you!

Comment: In the meantime, I'm using :

`./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit`

In order to run my Unit tests

Comment: Did you change anything in `bin/phpunit` code? Does your Kernel extend anything? Is it custom Kernel or Symfony's default one?

Comment: Did you compare your local version with the recipe to see if anything was changed since the file was created locally? https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/phpunit-bridge/4.1/bin/phpunit

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment this 3 lines in your **bin/phpunit** file :

```
// $classLoader = require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
// App\Kernel::bootstrapEnv('test');
// $classLoader->unregister();
```